# Comparing two dates results 0

Tags: php, date, datetime

so i'm currently making a small php application and I need to compare two dates to get the number of days between them.
I sadly can't use datediff() since the php version is 5.2.

I've search how to do and I found a lot of answers but I always have the same problem. When I make the difference between my dates, I always got 0 as a result.

```
function date_diff($dateFrom, $dateTo) {
    echo $dateFrom->format('d-m-Y') . " : " . $dateTo->format('d-m-Y') . '<br/>';
    $diff = abs($dateTo-$dateFrom);

    return sprintf
    (
        "%d Days, %d Hours, %d Mins, %d Seconds",
        intval( $diff / 86400 ),
        intval( ( $diff % 86400 ) / 3600),
        intval( ( $diff / 60 ) % 60 ),
        intval( $diff % 60 )
    );
}
```

I currently use this function and the parameters are here :

```
    while ($donnees = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
        $date = new DateTime($donnees['Date']);


    $date = date_create($date->format("Y-m-d"));
    $today = new DateTime();

    echo $utilDate->date_diff($date, $today);
```

My $date and $today variables are not empty, so I don't understand why this code doesn't work.
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Do you want the difference in seconds using timeStamp or difference in years/months/days/hours/minutes/seconds?

Comment: I want the difference in days, but i've a day, hour, min, sec display for the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think $dateTo and $dateFrom are objects and you are doing a substraction on them in `$diff = abs($dateTo-$dateFrom);`

Try `$diff = abs($dateTo->getTimestamp()-$dateFrom->getTimestamp());`

Comment: I can't use it, because the php version is 5.2

Comment: How about `format('U')` instead of `getTimestamp()` then?
http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.settimestamp.php indeed seems to be starting from 5.3; U-format should be available..
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the diff operator:

```
function date_diff($dateFrom, $dateTo) {
    echo $dateFrom->format('d-m-Y') . " : " . $dateTo->format('d-m-Y') . '<br/>';
    $diff = $dateNow->diff($dateTo);

    $day = $diff->format('%d');
    $hour = $diff->format('%h');
    $min = $diff->format('%i');
    $seconds = $diff->format('%s');

    return /*string involving above formats*/;
}
```